# Convert points(.shp file) to raster (.tif) in QGIS

Tags: shapefile, convert, geotiff-tiff

I have some points in .shp vector file and I need to convert them in .tif file with 1km x 1km resolution. The problem is - there are some points in one cell during conversion, and some values are missed. How can I convert these point without missing? Is there any function that will sum values in cell(in QGIS)?
Any suggestion are acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

First create a corresponding grid with:

**Vector / Research tool / Vector grid (polygon)**

Then use the join attributes with sum:

**Vector / Data management tools / Join attributes by location**

And finally rasterize the polygon according to the calculated attribute:

**Raster / Conversion / Rasterize**

Answer (score 0):

For me (QGIS 3.20.3), the following worked:

Raster → Conversion → Rasterize (Vector to Raster)

Afterwards:

1. Select your .shp as "Input layer"
2. Optionally, select "Field to use for a burn-in value"
3. For "Output raster size units" I chose "Pixels"
4. "Width" / "Height" define the dimensions of your raster
5. "Output extent" your .shp
6. Run (and have fun)